# OpenCV - What type of a result does cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack() return?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

Dear citizens of Stackexchange,

I am a 3rd grade Electrical and Electronics Engineer student, who is working on an image processing project using OpenCV 3.2 and Python 2.7.

What we would like to accomplish is to build up a system which can compensate the camera using **Lucas Kanade's Optical flow** method.

On the sample that was presented on the OpenCV's website, one of the inputs of the function `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` was `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack`.

I wanted to change that input to an output I have acquired from my another function. But the outputs of those two functions are mainly different in type.

What I would like to ask is, what type of topology is the following output format (matrix, array, etc.) that we get from `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()`?:

```
[[[ 582.  408.]]
 [[ 453.  373.]]
 [[ 483.  395.]]
 [[ 447.  298.]]
 [[ 589.  371.]]
 [[ 436.  358.]]
 [[ 624.  370.]]
 [[ 624.  413.]]
 [[ 470.  395.]]
 [[ 635.  378.]]
 [[ 630.  417.]]
 [[ 498.  395.]]
 [[ 427.  354.]]
 [[   6.  325.]]
 [[ 566.  381.]]
 [[  20.  323.]]
 [[ 532.  400.]]
 [[ 568.  374.]]
 [[ 457.  321.]]
 [[ 460.  413.]]
 [[ 471.  317.]]
 [[ 524.  399.]]
 [[ 586.  417.]]
 [[ 251.  184.]]
 [[ 289.  428.]]
 [[ 435.  342.]]
 [[ 635.  393.]]
 [[ 590.  387.]]
 [[ 160.   20.]]
 [[ 431.  296.]]
 [[ 449.  324.]]
 [[ 439.  371.]]
 [[ 466.  372.]]
 [[ 481.  465.]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()` is mainly used for detection of corners. See [THIS PAGE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-beta/d4/d8c/tutorial_py_shi_tomasi.html)

If you observe the `type` of the value returned by  `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()`, it is `numpy.ndarray`, which is a multi-dimensional array according to [THIS DOCUMENT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)

So the function `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()` returns all the **locations** of the corners present in the gray scale image.

This is what a typical output would look like, the corners are marked in blue:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the late response. I will go on with my research to find a way to convert the results i find from "mog2" function to the 3D array format,

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Since computing the optical flow for the whole image pixels is computationally immense, it it preferred to compute optical flow only around feature points. This method is called **sparse** optical flow. The first function i.e `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, computes sparse optical flow of the video around feature points you provide with the second function i.e `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack`. The output type of `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` is simply a 3D array.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer which quite helpful. This will actually lead me to search for a method to convert the features i detect via "mog2"   function into the 3D array format. 

Cheers,